# PCL 1.8.1 CMake Problems on windows

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, clion, point-cloud-library

I have followed the instructions on [this](http://unanancyowen.com/en/pcl181) page to install PCL 1.8.1 on my Windows 10 computer. No errors occured during the installation process and the installer quit successfully. My `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(MyProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package(PCL 1.8 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

set(SOURCE_FILES source/main.cpp)
add_executable(MyProject ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(MyProject ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at /cygdrive/c/Program Files/PCL 1.8.1/cmake/PCLConfig.cmake:44 (message):
  PCL can not be found on this machine
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /cygdrive/c/Program Files/PCL 1.8.1/cmake/PCLConfig.cmake:768 (pcl_report_not_found)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)
```

I am using Jetbrains CLion for development and CygWin for GCC, CMake and GDB. When I look into the `PCLConfig.cmake` file at lines 744-769 I find something strange:

```
# check whether PCLConfig.cmake is found into a PCL installation or in a build tree
if(EXISTS "${PCL_ROOT}/include/pcl-${PCL_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PCL_VERSION_MINOR}/pcl/pcl_config.h")
    # Found a PCL installation
    # pcl_message("Found a PCL installation")
    set(PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS "${PCL_ROOT}/include/pcl-${PCL_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PCL_VERSION_MINOR}")
    set(PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS "${PCL_ROOT}/lib")
    if(EXISTS "${PCL_ROOT}/3rdParty")
        set(PCL_ALL_IN_ONE_INSTALLER ON)
    endif(EXISTS "${PCL_ROOT}/3rdParty")

 elseif(EXISTS "${PCL_ROOT}/include/pcl/pcl_config.h")
    # Found a non-standard (likely ANDROID) PCL installation
    # pcl_message("Found a PCL installation")
    ... 

 elseif(EXISTS "${PCL_DIR}/include/pcl/pcl_config.h")
    # Found PCLConfig.cmake in a build tree of PCL
    # pcl_message("PCL found into a build tree.")
    ...

 else(EXISTS "${PCL_ROOT}/include/pcl-${PCL_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PCL_VERSION_MINOR}/pcl/pcl_config.h")
    pcl_report_not_found("PCL can not be found on this machine")  
 endif(EXISTS "${PCL_ROOT}/include/pcl-${PCL_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PCL_VERSION_MINOR}/pcl/pcl_config.h")
```

The first if-condition `if(EXISTS "${PCL_ROOT}/include/pcl-${PCL_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PCL_VERSION_MINOR}/pcl/pcl_config.h")` is true. I have checked it. In the directory `C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.1//include/pcl-1.8/pcl/` exists a file named `pcl_config.h`, but for some reason the last condition `else(EXISTS "${PCL_ROOT}/include/pcl-${PCL_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PCL_VERSION_MINOR}/pcl/pcl_config.h")` is exactly the same, and therefore also true. That's where the error comes from. I have no idea, what I should do now. Should I change the CMake file, so that only the first condition is true? Please help me.

Best regards, YpsilonZett

Comment: In `else()` branch condition is the same as in `if` clause, but it isn't used: as usual, `else` executed when neither `if` condition nor `elseif` ones are true. So, CMake thinks that `if` condition is false, that is required file doesn't exist. Are you sure that `PCL_ROOT` is set to `C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.1`? It should be set in `PCLConfig.cmake` script itself.

Comment: It is set in my system environment variables. I even added set(PCL_ROOT "C:/Program Files/PCL 1.8.1") to the PCLConfig.cmake file (at line 1), but the error stayed the same.

Comment: Er, did you install PCL into your Cygwin environment, since that is apparently, where you run your build.

Comment: `PCLConfig.cmake` file is generated by the project itself, and shouldn't be changed after installation. However, if you want to debug this script, you may add `message()` call for show value of expression, used in `if()`.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error,and successfully solve it. First,it says

```
if(EXISTS"${PCL_ROOT}/include/pcl-${PCL_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PCL_VERSION_MINOR}/pcl/pcl_config.h")
```

so check if you have `pcl_config.h`.
I find I have it in `/usr/include/pcl-1.12/pcl/pcl_config.h`. I guess that because my version is 1.12, it's too high, and `PCL_VERSION_MINOR` can not match.

I changed the code (though it is not recommended). Use `/usr/include/pcl-1.12/pcl/pcl_config.h` this kind path, not `${xxxxx}`, then it worked.